# Minus inside circle

Tags: css, unicode, fonts

I have this CSS:

```
.icon-plus-circled:before { content: '\e80f'; }
```

Which is displayed as a white plus inside black circle (Unicode I guess).

Need to make one more class, that would be a white minus inside black circle. But I can't find a Unicode code for that. Does anyone know?

---

Solved the problem. It was custom font.

Comment: Could you add the solution with a custom font in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Unicode character for a white minus inside black circle.

There is U+2296 CIRCLED MINUS “⊖”, though it is not clear whether you want to use that or rather U+229D CIRCLED DASH “⊝”.

The notation `'\e80f'` means U+E80F, which is a Private Use code point. This means that the Unicode standard does not assign any character to that code point and promises to never do so. The code point is *only* for use by private agreements and has no meaning outside such agreements. The code you are using probably sets the font to a privately encoded special font, embedded with `@font-face`. While this generally works (when implemented properly) in the the sense of displaying the specific symbol, it easily causes trouble e.g. when content is copied and pasted (losing the font assignment).

Consider using images instead. Created in sufficiently large size and then scaled to font size with CSS, they do the job reasonably well.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode characters you might be interested in:

- MINUS SIGN ([U+2212](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm)): − `&#8722;`
- HYPHEN-MINUS ([U+002D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm)): - `&#45;`
- CIRCLED MINUS ([U+2296](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2296/index.htm)): ⊖ `&#8854;`
- CIRCLED DASH ([U+229D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/229d/index.htm)): ⊝ `&#8861;`

Answer (score 1):

Unicode number: U+002D HTML-code: '&#45';
Here is the complete table: http://unicode-table.com/fr/#002D

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. It only gives the number and HTML character reference for the common Ascii hyphen, HYPHEN-MINUS in Unicode. It is not at all the same as MINUS SIGN. And there is no reason to use a character reference for it.

Answer (score 0):

> `content: '\e80f'` Which is displayed as a white plus inside black circle

U+E80F `` doesn't display as anything for me, that's a Private Use Area character that could render as anything or nothing.

There is no standard Unicode character for a filled circle with a plus *or* minus removed. Presumably you have some icon font where U+E80F looks like a circled plus. In that case you will have to look up the glyph set for that particular font to see if there is a matching minus.

None of the common icon fonts I know of use U+E80F for circled-plus so possibly you have a custom-made font (from Fontello or similar), in which case no-one can tell what the code point would be for a circled-minus without looking at the font file itself. Possibly the circled-minus might not have been included in it, in which case you'd have to create a new version of the icon font with it in.

Or, as Jukka mentions, switch to images (possibly SVG); icon fonts are a bit of a nasty hack.